# Create a new pandas column from map of existing column with mixed datatypes

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I want to categorise an existing pandas series into a new column with 2 values (planned and non-planned)based on codes relating to the admission method of patients coming into a hospital.

The codes fall into two main categories - planned and unplanned (=emergencies).

I cannot get the mapping to work and wonder if this is all due to differing datatypes.

The series has 3 planned codes and 12 unplanned codes. I have created a dictionary, you can see it has integers and strings ( I cannot change this coding) .

`adm_dictionary  = {'planned': [11, 12, 13], 'non_planned': ['2A', '2B', '2C', '2D',  28, 31, 32, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]}`

an example of my dataframe

`df2 = pd.DataFrame( {"ADMIMETH": ['11', '2D', '22']} )`

|  | ADMIMETH |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 11 |
| 1 | 2D |
| 2 | 22 |

Using map.

`df2['pl_nonpl'] = df2['ADMIMETH'].map(adm_dictionary)`

`df2`

|  | ADMIMETH | pl_nonpl |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 11 | NaN |
| 1 | 2D | NaN |
| 2 | 22 | Nan |

I have checked the dataypes as far as I can. Perhaps there is an easier method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try :

```
df2["pl_nonpl"] = df2["ADMIMETH"].map({f"{v}": k for (k, lst)
                                       in adm_dictionary.items() for v in lst})
```

​
Output :

```
print(df2)

  ADMIMETH     pl_nonpl
0       11      planned
1       2D  non_planned
2       22  non_planned
```

*Mappings :*

```
{'11': 'planned',
 '12': 'planned',
 '13': 'planned',
 '2A': 'non_planned',
 '2B': 'non_planned',
 '2C': 'non_planned',
 '2D': 'non_planned',
 '28': 'non_planned',
 '31': 'non_planned',
 '32': 'non_planned',
 '21': 'non_planned',
 '22': 'non_planned',
 '23': 'non_planned',
 '24': 'non_planned',
 '25': 'non_planned'}
```

Comment: weird, for me it worked for the string but not the integers

Comment: It means that your example `df2 = pd.DataFrame({"ADMIMETH": ['11', '2D', '22']})` does not describe your actual dataset. Besides that, the code works!

Comment: Thanks very much, yes had another look and its fixed.